# LINQ many to many query throws NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, linq, join, entity

I have a many to many relationship in my EntityFramework. I want query all "teilnehmer" which are related to a specific "mannschaft".

[image]

here is my query

```
var teilnehmerquery = (from teil in myEntities.Teilnehmer 
                       from man in teil.Mannschaft 
                       where 1==man.MNR 
                       select teil);
```

if i run it, the query throws a `NotSupportedException`.
What to do to get this working?

Comment: if i try

var teilnehmerquery = (from teil in myEntities.Teilnehmer from man in teil.Mannschaft where man.MNR==1 select teil);

it still dont works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var teilnehmerquery = myEntities.Mannschaft.Where( m => m.MNR == 1 )
                                .SelectMany( m => m.Teilnehmer );
```

Comment: Then i get "The method 'Select' is not supported."